# Event Listener for Multiple Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 select box and I wantwhich want to show different input (or text ) value. I don't know how can I show value if I select different select item ? 
For example: I selected 1 item from first select box AND I selected 1 item from second select box and I want show text value as result which as value of selected item.

Code :

```html
 <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Select</label>       
               <div class="form-group">
            <select id="kisi"class="form-control" name="rezaractip">
        <option value="1">1 </option>
        <option value="23">23 </option>
        <option value="96">96 </option>
       
        
      </select>
         </div>
                  </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Select</label>       
               <div class="form-group">
            <select id="kisi2"class="form-control" name="rezaractip">
        <option value="10">10 </option>
        <option value="230">230 </option>
        <option value="960">960 </option>
       
        
      </select>
         </div>
                  </div>
      <input id="result1 " value="Show1" />    
            <input id="result2 " value="Show2" />
```

I want if I select 1 item from first select box AND I select 1 item from second select box I want show result1 value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you were looking for something like this, but as I saw based on your description, you can achieve that with `jQuery`. Just trigger `change` event after selecting a value from `select` element, you just grab the current selected value, plus other `select value` and pass that value in specific input that you want to show.

Hope this helps!

```js
jQuery("#kisi2").on("change", function(){
  var selectedValue = jQuery(this).val();
  var firstSelectValue = jQuery("#kisi").val();
  var thisEl = jQuery("#result2").val(firstSelectValue + " " + selectedValue);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
                 <label>Select</label>       
               <div class="form-group">
            <select id="kisi"class="form-control" name="rezaractip">
        <option value="1">1 </option>
        <option value="23">23 </option>
        <option value="96">96 </option>
       
        
      </select>
         </div>
                  </div>
                    
                    <div class="form-group">
                 <label>Select</label>       
               <div class="form-group">
            <select id="kisi2"class="form-control" name="rezaractip">
        <option value="10">10 </option>
        <option value="230">230 </option>
        <option value="960">960 </option>
       
        
      </select>
         </div>
                  </div>
      <input id="result1" value="Show1" />    
            <input id="result2" value="Show2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I also wasn't really sure what you were looking for, I assumed you just wanted to show the values you select.

```
let selectOne = document.getElementById("kisi");
let selectTwo = document.getElementById("kisi2");
let resultOne = document.getElementById("result1");
let resultTwo = document.getElementById("result2");

selectOne.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    resultOne.setAttribute("value", event.target.value);
});

selectTwo.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    resultTwo.setAttribute("value", event.target.value);
});
```